# PowerBI Running Total in Matrix based on Date

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have a matrix in PowerBI with two row filters (name and team) and columns as 12 dates starting from current month. I have a measure that I display for each month, but I want it to display as a running total rather than just as the value for each month.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
Rolling 12 Month = calculate([12 Month],filter(all(Planning[Month]),Planning[Month]<=max(Planning[Month])))
```

where Planning[Month] defines the column header and 12 Month is this measure:

```
   12 Month = sum([12MonthK])
```

where [12MonthK] is just a column of values.

The only code I've gotten to actually create a running total is this:

```
RTTest = If( Not ISEMPTY(Planning),      VAR _maxDate = max(Planning[Month])    Return     calculate(  [YTD 12 Month], Planning[Month]<=_maxDate, all(Planning)))
```

but this running total just completely ignores any filters (the running total is the same for each name/team combo).

Comment: ALL(Planning) removes all filters in that table. Maybe with ALLEXCEPT(Planning,Planning[Team],Planning[Name]). Or something similar

Comment: @mxix When I made that modification, it was no longer a running total and just gave values per month.